# What may be causing "fails the check integrity"?

Tags: 7, rules

I need some help with the [Rules](https://www.drupal.org/project/rules) `fails the check integrity` issue. I am running the Rules version 7.x-2.7. It works most of the times and appears to be suddenly.

When I checked on the dblog it has error message like so:

> the action Set a data value () fails the integrity check and cannot be
>   executed

After clearing all the Drupal caches, it will start working again. It had a message like  Action was marked dirty, but passes the integrity check now and is active again.

This is a screenprint of the issue.

[image: rules error screen]

Comment: Hi, Binod. The key part of the "fails the integrity check" message is missing. It should be followed with "Error: ..." and then a message. If you're still having this problem please include it if you can. Also, it wouldn't hurt to update your module to most recent version.

Comment: Some module is probably missing. Try to enable recently disabled modules.

Answer (score 1):

#### Possible reasons

***Some*** reasons (pretty sure it is an incomplete list ...) that may help to pinpoint the reason for this typical message are like so:

- Some module is missing "now" (which was there when the rule was added). It could well be a recently disabled, or uninstalled module.
- The rule (or Rules Component) refers (in a Rules Condition or Rules Action) to a machine name of a field that is "no longer there".
- The rule (or Rules Component) refers to a Rules Component that is no longer there, or, as a variation, something changed in a Rules Component (eg the data type of a parameter) so that it is no longer compatible with the way some Rule is trying to execute that Rules Component.
- The rule (or Rules Component) refers to a content type (or more generic an entity type) that is no longer there, or a role that was removed.
- The rule (or Rules Component) has a Rules Condition or Rules Action, which is provided by some module, based on some logic in that module. A good example of this can be found in the [Content Access](https://www.drupal.org/project/content_access) module: the [ACL](https://www.drupal.org/project/acl) module seems to be a [weak module dependency](http://cgit.drupalcode.org/content_access/tree/content_access_rules/content_access_rules.rules.inc?h=7.x-1.x#n113) of the [Content Access](https://www.drupal.org/project/content_access) module, i.e. the Rules Action with machine name `content_access_action_user_grant` is only available if, and for as long as, [ACL](https://www.drupal.org/project/acl) is enabled (if you disable the ACL module, then any rule that has such `content_access_action_user_grant` action will show such "*... fails the integrity check*".

#### Possible resolutions

Depending on what the actual reason is, these are possible remedies for it:

- Re-enable recently disabled modules:

  - if any such module adds an extra content type with some related fields, and any of your rules still refer to them, then that would cause the typical error message.
  - if the existence of any such module is used to provide some extra Rules Condition or Rules Action, then any of your rules that still refer to those conditions/actions would cause the typical error message.
- If you know/remember which entity some field (which got deleted) referred to, then manually adding that field again (with identical machine name) should make the error message go away.
- ...