# What is the best order of content deletion on Drupal sites?

Tags: 7, views

Whenever I try to clean up a site.

I delete stuff in the wrong order, and then the site breaks.

Any guidelines on how to do this?

Content first, then content type? Blocks, views, what to delete first and in what order so things don't break?

Comment: Hi, strange, I've never had an issue with deleting a content type, it even tells you that all the content of that type  will be removed. A safe way to go would be to remove content first. Maybe you have some references tied to the content that do not get removed and are causing the issue?

Comment: Not only that, tons of stuff can confict, views, blocks , pages, ect..I'm looking for safe deleting protocol

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, delete content first, before you delete the content type. It won't actually break anything in core Drupal if you do delete the type first, but you'll end up with orphaned content; which can be a pain.

Beyond that it comes down to what custom/contrib modules you have installed, and how they're being used. There are hundreds of modules that make use of nodes/content types, all in different ways, so whether or not you would need to do anything specific for each of those depends on the module itself, and what it's expecting.

For example, deleting content and content types may or may not break a particular View, depending on how it's configured (maybe there's a custom preprocess function relying on the content type field not being empty).

Deleting a content type provided by a Feature might break something in that feature if there's custom code relying on it.

Blocks don't have any relation to nodes/content types by default, so if you have something installed which connects them, you might need to do something specific to avoid that module producing errors.

TLDR; there's no single answer - list out the modules you have installed, work out which ones of those have interaction with nodes and content types, and come up with a basic plan of action for each that you follow before deleting.

If that's too much work, then just make sure you remove *everything* in your site that relates to those nodes or content types before deleting them.

Comment: I just tried, 1 content, 2 content type but the the links are still listed, so I have to go delete them one by one...isn't there a way to delete from top to bottom, so one deletion kills all content in one shot?

Comment: Do you mean menu links? I believe the link will be deleted if you added it on the node edit form, but not if you added it manually.

Comment: https://ftp.drupal.org/files/projects/menu_editor-7.x-1.0-beta3.tar.gz need to use that to properly deal with links

Comment: Yeah that's kind of the point I was making - unless that module has code to do "something" when nodes are deleted, you'l need to do it manually

Answer (score 1):

This question is a typical "tough topic" in the context of configuration management (not just in the context of a Drupal site). What makes it more challenging is that Drupal doesn't offer many facilities to perform "impact analysis", something like "*I want to remove this thing, so before doing so, how can I find out where it is being used?*". And the more critical your site (system) is, the more important it becomes to be able to predict, 100% sure, what the answer.

So if you're not sure/comfortable enough, then another approach that will prevent your site from breaking because of such cleanup operations is to try to "*copy everything-that-is-not-to-be-deleted to a (temporary) staging site, QA-test this staging site until it looks OK, and then use that staging site as your cleaned-up version of your site*".

To perform such copy operation, there are some typical Drupal modules / facilities you can take advantage of, as further detailed below.

*Attention*: this approach is going to take (way) more effort, but the quality of the ultimate result is (should be) way better also. And pretty sure it will prevent all kinds of situations that typically breaks your site when deleting things in your real site.

## Export/import functions

Use the typical export/import functions to copy all sorts of configuration related objects, such as views, rules, etc. The [Features](https://www.drupal.org/project/features) module is going to be a great help to at least create an inventory of all sorts of configuration items (fields, content types, etc) you should take into consideration.

While using functions such as import, Drupal error messages may tell you about the missing pieces you forgot. Such as in the question about "[What may be causing 'fails the check integrity' in Rules?](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/164984/rules-fails-the-check-integrity-issue)". Too bad, but that's what the purpose is of a staging site, right? And your real site should not be impacted by that ...

Using this approach, you're going to have a hard time to create "orphan" situations, such as a menu link that points to nowhere.

## Migrate D2D

Perform a [Drupal-to-Drupal data migration](https://www.drupal.org/node/1813498). Here is a quote from that community documentation:

> The [Drupal-to-Drupal data migration module (migrate_d2d)](https://www.drupal.org/project/migrate_d2d) extends the framework provided by the [Migrate](https://www.drupal.org/project/migrate) module to support migration of content and data from one Drupal installation to another. It understands the core schemas of Drupal 5, Drupal 6, and Drupal 7, as well as the contributed [CCK module](https://www.drupal.org/project/cck) for versions 5 and 6.

Make sure to have a look at the **migrate_d2d_ui** submodule also. Here are some details about it (from the [Drupal-to-Drupal data migration](https://www.drupal.org/project/migrate_d2d) project page):

> With migrate_d2d 2.1, we introduced a wizard-based UI for defining your Drupal-to-Drupal migrations. The wizard is appropriate for non-technical users to configure and run the Drupal-to-Drupal migration, and/or when you don't have to do any special manipulation of data along the way.
>
> Enabling the migrate_d2d_ui module will add an "Import from Drupal" subtab to the Migrate dashboard - visit that tab, enter the credentials for your source Drupal database (versions 5, 6, or 7), and follow the steps to define how your legacy content maps to the destination Drupal 7 site.

Obviously, in your case you'd only want to migrate the content that is not to be deleted.

**Note**: This [Migrate](https://www.drupal.org/project/migrate) module is now also part of core in Drupal 8. So the time invested in learning about it to get to Drupal 7, will increase your Drupal 8 readiness for later on also.